# How to serialize a big json file into Http response body without consuming a lot of memory?

Tags: json, json.net

I have a json file with the structure as below -

```
{
    id:"#1",
    type:'someType',
    data:
     [
       {datapoint 1},.........{datapoint2}
     ]

}
```

The datapoints could be ranging from 10 - 1,000,000+.
Currently I follow the recommendation [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm) of Json.Net to serialized the json file to the Http Response body stream. However, the memory usage still looks high. The serialization code is as below.

```
 var jsonObjectToBeSerialized=GeographyVisualization;
 var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";

        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            ContractResolver = JsonSerializerSettings.CamelCaseResolverInstance
        };

        var stringConverter = new StringEnumConverter
        {
            NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
        };

        serializer.Converters.Add(item: stringConverter);

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(response.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.None;
            serializer.Serialize(writer, jsonObjectToBeSerialized);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        }
```

I there a way to lower the memory usage?

Comment: Did you try setting `Response.Buffer = false;`?  See [Why do we use Response.ClearHeaders()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6592864/3744182).

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply. It seems there is no Response.Buffer in .Net core 2.2. Is there any alternative?